# Error when add node programmatically

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new in Drupal, and I want to create a website which get all news data from my old site.
I tried to use node API to create node base on my old data. It worked but when I edit my new node, I get an error : "Alias already in use".
I tried adding simple node with title and body and get the same issue.
Please help me!!
Many thanks!

Comment: you probably have duplicates nodes.

Check "Generate automatic URL alias" box in your node path settings to generate an "mynode-1" for debuging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have duplicates nodes. Check "Generate automatic URL alias" box in your node path settings to generate an "mynode-1" for debuging